# mysql db open to all host connections

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user set to have access from %, wildcard.

This "GOD" user also has access to every db.

Do I have to open up the db itself to allow connections from any host?

I realize this is very dangerous for production, but I'm not working in a production environment.  Just playing around with it and can't get it to work.

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'myP@s$w0rd';
```

This grants user access to `foo` db for `bar` user from `%` anywhere, with the password identified.

I'm trying it but it's not working.  As far as I've read, this is should be opening it up to anything, but it's not.

```
define('DB_HOST','98.76.54.321',true);
define('DB_USER','bar',true);
define('DB_PASS','myP@s$w0rd',true);
define('DB_DBAS','foo',true);

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_DBAS);
if (!$link) { 
   echo 'FAIL! : '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
else { echo 'Success.'; }
```

Comment: aren't you missing a single quote after `%`?

Comment: sorry, fixed.  But the issue isn't with the mysql syntax, but when I'm trying to connect via php.  My php syntax is valid, I will post it as well.

Comment: So does the host itself allow access to MySQL's port 3306 from any client? Unless the firewall is wide open on 3306 and `skip-networking` isn't enabled in my.cnf you wouldn't be able to connect from remote hosts regardless of granted permissions.

Comment: You are terminating with `Unable to establish a DB connection` but did you check `mysqli_connect_error()` to see _why_ it can't connect?

Comment: I had in other iterations, but it doesn't show an error code.

Comment: Try to flush your database, that refreshes the list of allowed hosts (that's one of the things this command does):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Comment: Flush the table? Privs? All the things?

Comment: Since you're using it procedurally, [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) actually use `mysqli_error()` in that context, different from what I expected via `mysqli_connect_error()`.

Comment: Don't forget to turn on error reporting if you haven't.  `mysqli_connect()` will issue warnings on failure... `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: "Unknown MySQL server host 'x.x.x.x:3306' (3)"

Comment: found it.  Port doesn't go with IP, goes in it's own little spot. `mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DATABASE,PORT);`

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_connect() take a field for port, so port isn't mashed in with the host.

```
mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DATABASE,PORT);
```